# Is blank app (Xamarin portable) actually a combination

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

of :
- an Android class library
- an iOS class library
- and an pcl. 
?

Can i create an fully functionnal app with these three projects in a solution instead of simply create a blank app ? 
It's just for my education.

Comment: Yes and No. You can use in class library platform specific classes (UIViewController, Activity, etc) but you won't be able to run it as stand alone app. You will need a host app for that.

Comment: Ahah you again ! :D 
Ok !  but I need to be sure that i can put all the operations, application logic, the views, data access (all the things you put in a blank app) into theses projects which constitute app1.

And, in the host app, say something like : app1.letsGo() and then, app1 know how to run itself (going to view2 from main view etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A blank Xamarin app template (Portable) consists of a shared PCL and a platform app (not a library) for each selected platform.  You're correct that there is nothing in the template that you couldn't create by hand.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) So, even if i need an host app, technically, i can create all the "logic", the architecture and the views chain of the application in the class librairies ?

The goal is having an host app which is an empty shell.

Comment: that is the Xamarin Forms approach.  Using the "classic" Xamarin approach you cannot share UI between platforms, but you can share domain/data/services/etc logic.

Comment: Yes but actually, i want to share an android class library to the android application project of the host app, and a iOS class library to the iOS application project of the host app.
Moreover, both android and iOS class librairies reference a pcl.

Host app must be a empty shell, and, in my librairies (android, iOS and PCL), must contains all of the logic, architecture view etc...

Comment: Yes, that should work

Comment: Ok :) Basically, we want to build an host app which contains multiples apps, each of them built independently by different dev teams, and they should not be installed on a phone by themselves. The host app team should integrate them directly in their host app.